# VMware virtual machine not showing on menu

Tags: linux-mint, vmware

I created a virtual machine on my Linux Mint 18.2 OS to run Windows 10.

However, after creating it, the virtual machine doesn't show on the menu

[image]

When I attempted to open the virtual machine using "open a virtual machine", it doesn't run.

[image]

I am able to start the virtual machine if I run it directly from it's directory

[image]

The problem is that if I run the virtual machine, I am unable to configure the settings
[image]

So how can I make the windows 10 virtual machine appear under the VMware menu? In order to configure the settings before running it. Alternatively, is it possible to configure the settings while running the virtual machine?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

go to the privacy settings and enable the "remember recently accessed files". Next step, open the VM via file manager, after this, the vm will be showed on VM list.